# Finding counterfeit coins

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, algorithms, recreational-mathematics

Suppose I have $N$ rare coins, of which $M \le N$ are counterfeits. I am blind. I ask an oracle who charges me a penny to tell me in yes/no answers whether there is a counterfeit in any group I show her. Is there a strategy to identify all $M$ coins with minimal cost, preferably something better than $O(N)$?

This sounds like a variant of the counterfeit coin problem but I cannot find a good solution.

EDIT: In the case of $M=1$, one obvious solution is on order of $\log_2(N)$ where you number each coin in order, in base $2$. Then test each group by digits wherever the coin has a 1 in that digit. Then the counterfeit should be identified by the oracle readout per digit, in base $2$.

Comment: Minimal worst-case cost, or minimal expected cost?

Comment: Worst-case. But if there is a good probabilistic algorithm I am interested

Comment: Do you know the value of $M$?

Comment: @Sten, good question. But I think if you don't know the value of $M$, the worst-case scenario is when $M=N$, in which case you'll wind up having to ask about each coin individually, since the oracle's answer will always be "yes."

Comment: An information-theoretic lower bound: The worst-case number of questions $Q$ must satisfy the inequality $2^Q\ge{N\choose M}$. E.g., it'll take at least $7$ questions to identify $4$ counterfeits among $8$ coins, since ${8\choose4}=70\gt2^6$.

Comment: @Sten, I edited the question.

Comment: To be more specific, for $M = 1$, the best worst case is $\lceil \log_2(N) \rceil$.

Comment: Some very specific cases: if $M = 0$ or $M = N$, then the answer is $0$. If $M = N-1$, the answer is $N-1$.

Comment: If $M=0$, then one question needs to be asked to ascertain no counterfeits. If $M=N$, then I suppose (without proof) that you have to query each coin, so N.

Comment: If it is indeed the case that you cannot do better in a group of K, all of which are counterfeits, than to query all of the K coins, then I think the worst case scenario has to be greater than M, right?

Comment: @player100 Your comment implies that $M$ is unknown. In this case, the optimal strategy is to ask about every coin individually.

Answer (score 6):

For $M=2$ you can do it in $2 \log_2 N$ by the same binary search as for $M=1$.  Split the coins into two halves and ask about one half.  If you get yes, ask about the other.  If you get yes again, you have two binary searches for one coin each.  If you get no, you are looking for two coins in $\frac N2$.  You save one question if you get a no the first time while you have not separated the pair because you don't have to ask about the second half.

The information theoretic approach would be to try to keep the probability of each answer close to $\frac 12$.  If you ask about a group of $k$ coins, the chance of a no answer is $\left( 1-\frac MN\right)^k$.
$$\left( 1-\frac MN\right)^k=\frac 12\\
k \log \left( 1-\frac MN\right)=-\log 2\\
k=-\frac {\log 2}{\log \left(1-\frac MN\right)}$$
This does not account for the effects of the coins being discrete, but if you have $10\%$ counterfeits you should ask about groups of $6$ or $7$

My proposed strategy for large $N$ and at least moderate $M$, which I have not proven optimal, would be to compute $k$ from the above and ask about a group of $k$ coins.  If you get no, discard the coins, update $N$ and continue.  If you get yes, solve the $k$ coins and update both $M,N$ for the next group.  Since the group will be small and you are not certain how many counterfeits are in it, it is probably optimal to just ask coin by coin.  There is an opportunity to optimize the endgame where $N$ is not large.

Comment: I think you could follow this algorithm for $M>2$ as well. If $M=3$, then you ask about each half. If the response is yes,  then no, then you know all 3 are in one half. If it is yes, yes, then you know it is 1, 2 or 2, 1. Since you don't know which one is 1, you can follow the algorithm for 2 on both piles.

Comment: @VVejalla:  I think the desired groups get smaller because you want a good chance of getting an empty group.  See my addition.

Comment: This is interesting. So, does this mean that I can improve the odds by adding real coins into the mix up to the next power of 2?

Comment: @player100:  no, you add uncertainty when you mix known real coins into the pile.  I just added the suggestion that you pull out $k$ coins, do them, then deal with the rest of the group with new $M,N$ values you get by subtracting the $k$ coins.

Comment: @RossMillikan I don't think this is optimal for $M = 2$. For example, let's say $N = 4$. Your strategy is to ask about $2$ coins. If the answer is "no", then you are done. If the answer is "yes", then you ask about the other $2$. If the answer is "no", then you are done, but if the answer is "yes", you still need to ask $2$ more questions, for a grand total of $4$ questions if $N = 4, M = 2$

Comment: Instead ask about $1$ coin. Then if the answer is yes, then you only need to ask two more questions for a total of $3$. If the answer is no, then you still only need to ask two more questions for a total of $3$. This way the worst case cost is $3$ rather than $4$.

Comment: @VVejalla:  I agree there is work to be done on the small numbers because of the breakage of single coins.  If we want to do that we need to define whether minimal is average or worst case.  I think you are right either way for $N=4, M=2$.  Your average is $3$.  "Mine" is $\frac 16\cdot 1 + \frac 16 \cdot 2+\frac 23 \cdot 4=\frac {19}6$, slightly worse.

Comment: @player100 said in the comments that it was worst case.

Comment: @VVejalla:  I suspect for the small groups, particularly because you don't know $M$ you should just ask coin by coin.  The gain comes if you ask about two or more and get a no.

Answer (score 1):

Let $f(n, m)$ be the optimal worst-case cost, $0 \le m \le n$. You already got that $f(n, 1) \sim \log_2(n)$. Specifically, $f(n, 1) = \lceil \log_2(n) \rceil$. Also $f(n, 0) = f(n, n) = 0$ since no guesses will be needed to determine the fakes.

$f(n, n-1)$: Since there is only one real coin, the only way to determine the real one is to go through all coins (except possibly the last one) - no point in splitting piles up. Therefore $f(n, n-1) = n-1$.

$f(4, 2)$: You can either ask about a pile of size $1$ or $2$ (no point in asking about a pile of size $3$ since it is guaranteed to have a counterfeit). If you ask about a pile of $1$, then that reduces to $1+\max(f(3, 1), f(3, 2)) = 1+\max(2, 2) = 3$. If you ask about a group of size $2$ and you get a "no" answer, you are done. If you get a "yes" answer, then you will have to ask $2$ more questions, so $f(4, 2) = 3$.

$f(n, 2)$: Let's ask about $k$ coins, $1 \le k < n$. If "no" is the response, then it becomes $1+f(n-k, 2)$. For the case where "yes" is the response, I will define a helper function, $g(a, b)$, which represents the optimal worst-case cost for where there are $2$ counterfeits total, $a$ is the size of the group of coins that is guaranteed to have at least $1$ counterfeit, $b$ is the size of the group with an unknown number of counterfeits (either $1$ or $0$). Then $f(n, 2) = \min(\max(1+f(n-k, 2), 1+g(k, n-k)) \forall k, 1 \le k < n)$.

$g(a, b)$: $g(a, 0) = f(a, 2)$, $g(1, b) = f(b, 1)$. We have two options - either ask about $k_1 (1 \le k_1 < a)$ from group $a$ or $k_2 (1 \le k_2 \le b)$ from group $b$. If we ask about $k_1$ and get a "yes" response, that becomes $1+g(k_1, a+b-k_1)$. If we get a "no" response, that becomes $1+g(a-k_1, b)$. If we ask $k_2$ and get "yes", that becomes $1+f(a, 1)+f(k_2, 1)$. If we get "no", that becomes $1+g(a,b-k_2)$. Therefore $g(a, b) = \min(\max(1+g(k_1, a+b-k_1), 1+g(a-k_1, b)) \forall k_1, 1 \le k_1 < a, \max(1+f(a, 1)+f(k_2, 1), 1+g(a,b-k_2)) \forall k_2, 1 \le k_2 \le b)$

Using this, I managed to find [A200311](http://oeis.org/A200311) in the OEIS. Note that the OEIS entry is shifted by two (i.e. A200311(n+2) = f(n, 2)) and the first entry is different. From that, I found that $$f(n, 2) = \left\lfloor 2\log_2(n-1) + 2\log_2 \left(\frac{7}{6} \right) \right\rfloor +_? 1$$

(I couldn't find the notation for "$x$ or $x+1$", so just made something up - hope it is clear)

What I noticed was that for the first group, you could take anything from $\approx n/4$ to $ \approx n/3$. For example, for $n = 400$, anything from $96 \approx \frac{400}{4}$ to $128 \approx \frac{400}{3}$ was okay for the size of the first guess. Anything else was suboptimal. In this range, the worst-case cost was the same whether the oracle answered "yes" or "no" to that query.

**Edit for f(n, m)**:

I will define a helper function, $g(p_1;p_2;...;p_k, b, c)$, for the optimal worst-case cost where $p_i$ represents the number of piles of size $i$ guaranteed to have at least one coin, $b$ coins not examined, and $c$ total counterfeits in the configuration.

The first query is equivalent to $g$, $$f(n, m) = g(\lbrack \rbrack, n, m)$$

Let's take a look at $g$ now. The base cases are $g(p_1;p_2;...;p_k, b, 1\cdot p_1 + 2\cdot p_2 + ... + k\cdot p_k + b) = 0$ and $g(p_1;p_2;...;p_k, b, p_1+p_2+...+p_k) = \sum_{i=1}^{k} p_i \cdot f(i, 1)$.

For any other time, we have a number of options: from a pile of size $t$ with a known counterfeit, we can ask any query up to size $m_1, 1 \le m_1 < t$. Let's say we pick $m_1$ from $t$. Then with a "yes" response, that makes $p_t$ go down $1$, $p_{m_1}$ go up $1$, and $b$ go up $t-m_1$. With a "no" response, that makes $p_t$ go down $1$ and $p_{t-m_1}$ go up $1$.

From the "$b$" pile, we can ask a query up to size $m_2, 1 \le m_2 \le \min(b, b-c+\sum_{i=1}^{k} k\cdot p_k)$. With a "yes" response, $p_{m_2}$ goes up $1$ and $b$ goes down $m_2$. With a "no" response, $b$ goes down $m_2$.

Using a Python program, I got the correct optimal worst-case cost (code at bottom). What I noticed was that $$f(n, n-k) = n-1$$ for a fixed $k$ after $n$ is sufficiently high. For example for $k = 7$, $f(n, n-7) \not = n-1$ only for $ n \le 10$. More generally, numerical results strongly suggest that $f(n, n-k) = n-1$ if $$n \ge \left\lfloor \frac{3k+1}{2} \right\rfloor$$

Equivalently, $f(n, m) = n-1$ for $$m \ge \left\lceil \frac{n}{3} \right\rceil$$

The Python code is rather slow - it bruteforces every possible branch. I didn't implement alpha-beta pruning as I could have.

```
def f(n, m, dic1 = {}, dic2 = {}):
    T = (n, m)
    if T in dic1:
        return dic1[T]
    if m == 0:
        dic1[T] = 0
        return 0
    if m == 1:
        dic1[T] = math.ceil(math.log2(n))
        return dic1[T]
    if n == m:
        dic1[T] = 0
        return 0
    elif n == m+1:
        dic1[T] = m
        return m

    dic1[T] = g((), n, m, dic1, dic2)

    return dic1[T]

def g(P, b, c, dic1, dic2):
    #precondition: P[-1] != 0
    #would also speed up computation since more memoization possibility
    T = (P, b, c)
    #T = (tuple, int, int)

    numPiles = sum(P)
    totalCoins = sum((i+1)*P[i] for i in range(len(P)))+b

    if T in dic2:
        return dic2[T]
    if c == numPiles:
        #one coin in each pile
        dic2[T] = sum(P[i]*f(i+1, 1, dic1, dic2) for i in range(len(P)))
        return dic2[T]

    if c == totalCoins:
        #all the remaining coins are counterfeits
        dic2[T] = 0
        return 0

    worstCase = math.inf
    for index in range(len(P)):
        if P[index] != 0:
            #can only ask if there is a pile with that many coins
            t = index+1 #to adjust for 0-based indexing
            for m1 in range(1, min(t-1, totalCoins-c)+1):
                tmpP = P[:t-1]+(P[t-1]-1,)+P[t:]

                firstNewP = tmpP[:m1-1]+(tmpP[m1-1]+1,)+tmpP[m1:]
                secondNewP = tmpP[:t-m1-1]+(tmpP[t-m1-1]+1,)+tmpP[t-m1:]

                while len(firstNewP) > 0 and firstNewP[-1] == 0:
                    #to make sure that the last element is not zero
                    firstNewP = firstNewP[:-1]

                while len(secondNewP) > 0 and secondNewP[-1] == 0:
                    #to make sure that the last element is not zero
                    secondNewP = secondNewP[:-1]

                comp = 1+max(g(firstNewP, b+t-m1, c, dic1, dic2), g(secondNewP, b, c, dic1, dic2))
                if comp < worstCase:
                    worstCase = comp

    for m2 in range(1, min(b, totalCoins-c)+1):
        if len(P) < m2:
            firstNewP = P+(0,)*(m2-len(P))
        else:
            firstNewP = P
        firstNewP = firstNewP[:m2-1]+(firstNewP[m2-1]+1,)+firstNewP[m2:]
        comp = 1+max(g(firstNewP, b-m2, c, dic1, dic2), g(P, b-m2, c, dic1, dic2))
        if comp < worstCase:
            worstCase = comp

    dic2[T] = worstCase
    return worstCase
```