# how many queries does it take to determine which 2 cards from a set of M are marked, if you can only query a subset at a time?

Tags: combinatorics

Suppose you have M face-down cards on a table, and 2 of them have an X on the hidden side.  You can pick any subset of the cards and query an oracle which will tell you "Yes" or "No" as to whether your subset contains at least one X-card.  How many queries does it take to guarantee that you can correctly identify the two X-cards?  (Or, given N queries, what is the maximum number M for which you can identify the 2 X-cards out of a set of M?)  I thought this would have a simple inductive answer that I could find, but I've been unable to find a formula.  (And I haven't even tried for marked sets larger than 2.)

Trivially, since N queries give $2^N$ possible answers and there are M(M-1)/2 possibilities, you need $2^N \geq M(M-1)/2$ , but this is not a sufficient condition.  For example, 4 queries is not enough to identify the two X-cards from a set of 6 cards.  (If your initial query set is of size 1, then if you get a "No", there are 10 possibilities remaining so 3 queries is not enough.  If your initial query set is of size 2 and you get a "Yes", there are 9 possibilities remaining so 3 queries is not enough.  And if you can't handle the case of a "Yes" for a size-2 set, you can't handle the case of a "Yes" for any larger set, since that would convey less information.)

Trivially, M-1 queries are enough for a set of M cards (check all of them individually except the last one).  7 appears to be the smallest set for which you can get the answer in M-2 or fewer queries (it's tedious to list the steps, but it's doable, unless I made a mistake).

Does this series have a name and known properties?  (And is there an analogous series for subsets of size 2 or larger?)

Comment: [This question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3587942/595055) might be helpful to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$2^N \geq M(M-1)/2$ is basically tight; the answer is within a constant of the smallest $N$ that satisfies this (and the constant can be reduced to $2$ or maybe $1$ if you do things carefully).

To show this, we can split the algorithm into two stages: before two sets which "split" the cards are identified, and after.

In the first stage, we split the entire range into two ranges of length $M/2$ (rounding off appropriately), and query each. If both are "Yes", we go into the second stage; otherwise, exactly one is "No" and the other is "Yes", and we can reduce our range appropriately. (Note that if the first range we query is "No" here, we save on a query.)

In the second stage, we have a set guaranteed to contain one of the hidden cards, and another set guaranteed to contain the other; and we can simply binary search on each of these sets independently, by testing half the range and iterating into the half guaranteed to contain the hidden card.

If you follow this process carefully, you'll see that this uses at most $2 \lceil\log(M)\rceil$ queries overall (where $\log$ is base $2$). But $2\log(M) = \log(M^2)$, which is within $1$ of $\log(M(M-1))$ as long as $M$ isn't too small.